# Automation of a debugging script using expect

Tags: expect

After running a command for debugging,the output of it is very big..so at some point it keeps asking

```
Type <return> to continue,or q <return> to quit
```

Now I want to automate these commands for different bugs.But this particular statement that I mentioned above keeps changing while debugging for different bugs.Sometimes it comes two times for one bug and sometime five times for another bug.How do I write an expect script to give the  i.e. the continue option for these?

Comment: In order continue, you need to press `enter` key only. Correct ? Then you can use `send \r` to simulate the same.

Comment: Yep I did that.But the number of times this statement occurs differs for different bugs

Comment: So I wanna automate it such that for whichever bug I will be dealing with,if this statement comes(any number of times )it must perform the send r command!Can.this be automated this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we don't know the order of occurence of some patterns or even the number of times, then `exp_continue` is the right command to use.

```
expect {
    <pattern1> {send "cmd1"; exp_continue}
    <pattern2> {send "cmd2"; exp_continue}
    <pattern3> {send "cmd3"}
}
```

In the above example, say `pattern1` and `pattern2` may not arrive in same order and the number of times of occurrence also varies, then `cmd1` and `cmd2` will be sent and the `Expect` will still run again.

The command `exp_continue` allows `Expect` itself to continue executing rather than returning as it normally would. This is useful for avoiding explicit loops or repeated expect statements.

By default, `exp_continue` resets the timeout timer. The timer is not restarted, if `exp_continue` is called with the `-continue_timer` flag.

In your case, we can write something like,

```
expect {
    "Type <return> to continue,or q <return> to quit" {send "\r";exp_continue}
    "some-more-patterns" {#handler_here}
}
```